# How to play next song in queue when the first song finished discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my discord music bot be able to play the next song in queue right after the fist song finished. Is there any way to do that?

This is my play function

```
queue = []

@client.command(name='play',help ='Play a song',aliases=['plays', 'p'])
async def play(ctx, url):
    global queue
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client
    queue.append(url)
    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue[0], loop=client.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
        del(queue[0])
        await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {player.title}')
```

Comment: I know there are already a lot of this type of question. but most of them weren't clear and had no replies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but it should work.

```py
queues = {}  # Dictionary with queues for each server


def queue(ctx, id):
    if len(queues) > 0 and queues[id] != []:
        voice = ctx.guild.voice_client
        audio = queues[id].pop(0)
        voice.play(audio, after=lambda x=None: queue(ctx, ctx.message.guild.id))


@client.command(name='play',help ='Play a song',aliases=['plays', 'p'])
async def play(ctx, url):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    guild_id = ctx.message.guild.id
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    audio = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=client.loop)
    if not voice.is_playing():
        async with ctx.typing():
            voice.play(audio, after=lambda x=None: queue(ctx, guild_id))
            voice.is_playing()
            await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {audio.title}')
    else:
        if guild_id in queues:
            queues[guild_id].append(audio)
        else:
            queues[guild_id] = [audio]

        await ctx.send("Added to queue.")
```

Or with queue as list:

```py
queue = []


def queued(ctx):
    if len(queue) > 0:
        voice = ctx.guild.voice_client
        audio = queue.pop(0)
        voice.play(audio, after=lambda x=None: queued(ctx, ctx.message.guild.id))


@client.command(name='play',help ='Play a song',aliases=['plays', 'p'])
async def play(ctx, url):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice.is_playing():
        async with ctx.typing():
            audio = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=client.loop)
            voice.play(audio, after=lambda x=None: queued(ctx))
            voice.is_playing()
            await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {audio.title}')
    else:
        queue.append(audio)
```

Comment: I'm trying to make this for one server. Will this code still work if queue is a list?

Comment: No, but it'll work with one server as dictionary. However, i added code variation with queue as list.